# La url de mi vue router no la reconoce

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, electron

Estoy ocupando Vue cli

Y he creado mi menu, Lo cual está así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ME muevo en esos dos botones que tengo ahorita y cuando accedo a productos tengo otro menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que es crear, buscar, actualizar, listar, al darle crear si se muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando quiero darle clic a buscar, actualizar o listar. me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad independientemente  de cual sea el primer que le de clic si se muestra, pero al darle clic en otro router link. no se muestra.

Mis rutas las tengo así

```html
Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: ()=> import('../views/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/producto',
    name: 'producto',
    component: () => import('@/views/Productos/Producto.vue'),
    children:[
      {
        path: '/producto/crear',
        name:'crear-producto',
        component: () => import('@/views/Productos/Crear.vue')
      },
      {
        path:'/producto/listar',
        name:'listar-productos',
        component: () =>  import('@/views/Productos/Lista.vue')
      },
      {
        path:'/producto/actualizar-varios',
        name:'actualizar-varios',
        component: () => import('@/views/Productos/Actualizar.vue')
      },
      {
        path:'/producto/buscar',
        name:'buscar-producto',
        component: () => import('@/views/Productos/Buscar.vue')
      },
      {
        path:'/productos/importar',
        name:'importar-productos',
        component: () => import('@/views/Productos/Importar.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
  
]
```

mis views están así

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="my-4 mx-4" >

      <div id="nav">
        <router-link class="btn btn-primary " :to="{name:'home'}">Inicio F1</router-link> 
        <router-link class="btn btn-primary mx-1" :to="{name:'producto'}">Productos F2</router-link>

      </div>

     <router-view > </router-view>

  </div>
</template>
```

Y en productos el principal está así

```html
<template>
    <div class=" my-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="list-group">

                    <router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="{name:'crear-producto'}"> Crear </router-link>
                    <router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="{name:'buscar-producto'}"> Buscar</router-link>
                    <router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="{name:'actualizar-varios'}"> Actualizar Variós</router-link>
                    <router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="{name:'listar-productos'}"> Listar </router-link>      
    
                </div> 

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 my-3">
                 <router-view ></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name :'producto'

}
</script>
```

Tengo un router view dentro de otro router view

les he puesto ya nombre y en las rutas  también les puse la relacion de que tiene cada router view con cada ruta y su componente

Me he percatado.. de esto..

**Si Yo estoy en la ruta  principal 
http://localhost:8080/producto  Y si recargo si se muestra todo el menu,
 pero cuando accedo a http://localhost:8080/producto/crear   si se muestra, pero si recargo la pagina me dice que esa ruta no existe.**

Esto pasa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo más que me he percatado.

**Si yo estoy en la ruta**

```
/producto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me cargan mis archivos Js <-----

pero si me muevo a buscar/ si me va cargar(porque es el primero que le dice clic)

Y se agrego un nuevo archivo JS [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora si me muevo a Crear/actualizar

Se crea una carpeta producto/js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí ya mostró error.

(ahora entonces para que esto funcione) me di cuenta que
nuevamente(recargando mi ruta principal)

```
/producto
```

Si le doy clic en Buscar/crear/Actualizar (la que sea primera) si se va mostrar

Todo perfecto hasta ahí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora  si regreso nuevamente a (INICIO) sin recargar la pagina y sin darle clic a otra opcion de mi menu productos()

al regresar a inicio y de nuevo volver a prouducto y doy clic en otra opcion del menú no me muestra error.  entones para que mi menu funcione  tengo que  regresar a INICIO, VOLVER a producto y darle clic en la opcion que quiera. en si tengo que recargar el componente(Producto) pero no se que esta pasando ...

Comment: reemplaza `<router-view > </router-view>` por `<router-view></router-view>`

Answer (score 0):

También lo que podrías hacer es remplazar los `:to="{name:'nombre'}"`:

```
<router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="{name:'crear-producto'}"> Crear </router-link>
```

En vez de poner el name de la definido en el router, poner el nombre path definido en el router y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<router-link class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :to="/producto/crear"> Crear </router-link>
```

(Debería de funcionar)

Comment: es que en resumen  la  url /producto/crear si accedo directamente no la muestra